# How to reactivate Typhoon assembly in iOS share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon, ios-extensions

I'm working on an app that contains a share extension, and both it and the container app use Typhoon assemblies for DI. The first time the share extension is launched, everything works fine, but any subsequent launches of the extension in the same session causes a crash the first time any one of the dependencies is referenced because all dependencies are now nil.

Both the app and extension use Plist integration, and so the assemblies are only run once. As such, when the extension is launched after the first time, the storyboard & view controllers are not injected with their dependencies. How can I make sure Typhoon injects its dependencies in the share extension each time it launches?

Comment: there was a question like this somewhere in Typhoon github's issue list - checking what outcome was, if any.  Meanwhile someone will provide an answer ASAP.